# make variables from an array where some variables are arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i would like to ask, how to make variables from the array, where some variables are variables and some arrays.

for ex:
i have an array for global:

```
$globals = array("routes","_ARGS","DB_SERVER","DB_USER","DB_PASS","DB_NAME","conn","mysql_tables","validity_of_fields_array");
```

and one of the variable is `array "validity_of_fields_array"`.

so i made a code that if some variable ends with word array, the script sets the variable an array instead just a variable

```
function framework_routes($rout_arg){

    global $globals;

    foreach($globals as $value) {   

        if(substr($value, count($value)-6) == strtolower("array")){         
            global $$value = array;             
        } else {    
            global $$value; 
        }
    }
```

this part (`global $$value;`)   sets the variable ok, but this part (`global $$value = array;`) throws me an error!

if i set `global $$value[];` instead of `global $$value = array;`

it throws me an error too.

May be someone knows how to for-each variables from an array, when some of variables are arrays?

Thank you and have a nice day !

Justin

Comment: Do not abuse of `global` keyword. `global` in a function means your function will be allowed to access a variable that is set outside the function scope, so basically you try to access a constant variable for example. In your loop `foreach($globals as $value)`, do not necessary put a `global ` before `$$value` as it is already setted in your function. Also, why the doubles `$` ?

Comment: this worked. $$value. Thanks man!!!